# Javascript setTimeout function with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, settimeout

I'm new to JQuery and Javascript, I try to write a small setTimeout function but it seems not to work. Below is my code, can some one help out by pointing out what is wrong here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>countdown</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script>
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var timeVal = $("#input").val();
        var mainTimeVal = timeVal.split(":");
        var minute = parseInt(mainTimeVal[0]);
        var second = parseInt(mainTimeVal[1]);
        //console.log( second);

        setTimeout(function () {

            if (minute == 0 && second == 0) {
                alert("no time left");
            }
            else if (second !== 0) {
                second--;
            }
            else {
                minute--;
                second = 60;
            }
            second--;
        }, 1000);
    });
  </script>
</head>
 <body>
   <input type="text" id="input" value="25:23"/><br>
   <button type="button" id="submit" value="send"></button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code executes on `.click` on the `submit` button - which means it only executes when you click the button. Also using `setTimeout` you are only running it once, and by the inner logic of the function it seems you want it to be ongoing. Substitute `setTimeout` to `setInterval` to keep it running.

`$("#submit").click(function(){
        var timeVal = $("#input").val();
        var mainTimeVal = timeVal.split(":");
        var minute = parseInt(mainTimeVal[0]);
        var second = parseInt(mainTimeVal[1]);
        //console.log( second);

```
    setInterval(function () {

        if (minute == 0 && second == 0) {
            alert("no time left");
        }
        else if (second !== 0) {
            second--;
        }
        else {
            minute--;
            second = 60;
        }

        $('#input').val(minute + ':' + second);
    }, 1000);
});`
```

Comment: i did but it seems not to work, if it works for you, can you pls produce a fiddle? @Velimir

Comment: to be exact you want the timer to keep on counting after you've pressed `submit` and after time is lapsed you want to fire the alert correct?

Comment: yes exactly, i did replace setTimeout with setInterval, the time counts down but the interval is " seconds but i want it to lapse by 1 second. @Velimir

Comment: `}, 100);` this last parameter is in milliseconds so 100 means 1/10 of a second, use `1000` as it was before to accomplish a 1 second intervals

Comment: sorry that last part I mistakenly saw in another answer, check out the edit - this function works now - tested

Comment: exactly the same code i got, it works but reduces with 2 seconds! That i don't understand why...and after reducing minutes by -1, minutes doesn't reduce anymore, seconds run into negative! @Velimir

Comment: you have an extra `second--` after all the if/else conditions, that makes the counter go 2 seconds on each turn and also makes it miss the `(second==0)` case because it goes to -1 straight away

Comment: Also you'll need to clear the timeout once it goes in the block with the alert - so it doesn't spit out alerts each second. Check this out - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code slightly and created a fiddle: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m39gepxr/)

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    var timeVal = $("#input").val();
    var mainTimeVal = timeVal.split(":");
    var minute = parseInt(mainTimeVal[0]);
    var second = parseInt(mainTimeVal[1]);

    setTimeout(function () {

        if (minute == 0 && second == 0) {
            alert("no time left");
        }
        else if (second !== 0) {
            second--;
        }
        else {
            minute--;
            second = 60;
        }
        second--;

        $('#input').val(minute + ':' + second);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

have to recursive to make call and call again....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>countdown</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
 <body>
   <input type="text" id="input" value="25:23"/><br>
   <input type="button" id="submit" value="send"></input>
    <script>
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var timeVal = $("#input").val();
        var mainTimeVal = timeVal.split(":");
        var minute = parseInt(mainTimeVal[0]);
        var second = parseInt(mainTimeVal[1]);
        //console.log( second);

        setTimeout(function () {

            rece();
            function rece(){
            if (minute == 0 && second == 0) {
                alert("no time left");
                console.log('no time left')
            }
            else if (second !== 0) {
                second--;
                console.log('second');
                rece();
            }
            else {
                minute--;
                second = 60;
                console.log('minute');
                rece();
            }
            second--;
            }

        }, 100);
    });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```